# The scientific one!

Tags: knowledge, cipher, visual, rebus

The picture below will lead you to the correct answer.

The answer consists of two parts(_____ _____).

Try see if you can make sense of it!

[image]

Oh, and don't forget.... the scientific one!

Hint

> [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is:

> Thaumoctopus mimicus

Reasoning:

Starting with the discovery of @shoover that

> the red numbers to the right of the track denote vowels, and those below the track denote consonants (thanks, @shoover!)

I then

> noticed that the red numbers are used as position markers, marking the position of the corresponding letter in the word being constructed.
>  Four words are constructed, each corresponding to a different box color. For example, using the blue boxes, the constructed word has a 'c' in the first position, 'a' in the second position, 'm' in the third position, etc.

Solving each of these, I generated

> these four words: 'camouflage' 'eight' 'animal' 'mimic'
> 'Eight' and 'animal' seem to refer to an octopus. 'camouflage' and 'mimic' seem to refer more specifically to the mimic octopus. The puzzle reminds us to use the 'scientific one', which I interpret as the scientific name. The scientific name of the mimic octopus is Thaumoctopus mimicus.

Note:

> I did not explicitly use the image of the molecule in my solution. I am assuming that this is a visual hint instructing us to combine vowels and consonants together.

Comment: You got it! The correct reasoning and exactly the answer i wanted. Well done :)

Comment: The water molecule and the underline was just there to hint "underwater"

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer, thinking out loud.

The red and white thing above the line is

> a water molecule, with 1 Oxygen atom and 2 Hydrogen atoms.

This makes me think

> of the saying "water over the dam."

So let's see what we can make of the boxes.

The grid represents

> the alphabet (26 squares) with an X in each vowel's square.

Based on the hint,

> let's look across and then down.

For the boxes to the right,

> the letters in red correspond to the vowels.

YOU

> O=4, U=5

AS

> A=2

ARE

> A=8, E=10

YIELD

> I=2, E=1

PLAIN

> A=5, I=3

STAR

> A=1

BRICK

> I=2

LIFT

> I=4

For the boxes underneath,

> the numbers correspond to the consonants

AM

> M=1

COME

> C=5, M=3

GET

> G=3, T=5

HI

> H=4

MOON

> M=4, N=2

LIE

> L=6

LOAF

> L=7, F=6

ME

> M=3

CAGE

> C=1, G=9

From there,

> I'm stuck. I don't know what to do with these numbers, which range from 1-10. And I don't know whether the colors of the boxes are significant, or why there's an image of a running track.

Comment: You're definitely on the right track(;)) Just try to somehow connect the dots...